# Starting Activity problems in AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am facing one problem in `AsyncTask` in my application in Android. The problem is, I am starting another `Activity` from `AsyncTask` in my application which runs fine when its layout has simple `Button`, but when I am using `ImageButton` its giving me error of handler and looper.loop. I am not getting the reason why this kind of error is occurring. I am displaying menus with images in calling `Activity`.

Can anybody suggest me what is the problem in this and how can I achieve this kind of functionality?

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (Dialog != null && Dialog.isShowing()) {
       Dialog.dismiss();
       locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
       Intent homeIntent = new Intent(ATMActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), HomeMenuActivity.class);
       homeIntent.putExtra("lat", latitude);
       homeIntent.putExtra("lng", longitude);
       startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
}
```

#### XML File :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/atm_icon"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Another Activity Class :-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.home);

       Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
       btn.setHint("ATM");
       float latitude = getIntent().getFloatExtra("lat", 0);
       float longitude = getIntent().getFloatExtra("lng", 0);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Floats:- " + latitude + "," + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code for details.

Comment: Please post code that is generating Exception

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
 super.onPostExecute(result);
 if (Dialog != null && Dialog.isShowing()) {
  Dialog.dismiss();
 locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(ATMActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), HomeMenuActivity.class);
 homeIntent.putExtra("lat", latitude);
 homeIntent.putExtra("lng", longitude);
 startActivity(homeIntent);
}

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/atm_icon"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
  btn.setHint("ATM");
  float latitude = getIntent().getFloatExtra("lat", 0);
  float longitude = getIntent().getFloatExtra("lng", 0);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Floats:- " + latitude + "," + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Sorry for posting code in comment but as i don't have much reputation i can't put it in answer.. hope you guys understand that...

Comment: Thank you vivek for editing my question in proper format...I am new so i am not used to with format of the site. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the full stack trace it's hard to say for sure, but my best guess is you're actually getting a `ClassCastException`.

Your `ATMActivity` is trying to cast `imageButton1`, defined in xml as an `ImageButton`, to a `Button`. This is not possible, as the latter is not a superclass of the former.

```
// Can't do below: Button is not a superclass of ImageButton
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

Since you're starting the activity from the onPostExecute of an AsyncTask, you'll probably find some stuff mentioning a looper/handler in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are playing with UI thread(updating UI thread) from a non-UI thread, that is causing you the problem. If you want to update anything from the non-UI thread you need to put the code inside the `runOnUiThread()`.

```
Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // here you can add stuff to Update the UI.
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hello lalit, i am not getting your suggestion but i am simply calling activity from onPostExecute and in the xml layout i have only one image button. If in place of image i simply replace it with button then everything is running absolutely fine..

Comment: you have to include the code in the question itself, its unreadable in the comments as you have added.

Comment: lalit thanks for your quick response. i posted the sample code. please go through it once..